# Directed graph whose adjacency matrix admits only 0 as eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory, eigenvector

Let $G$  be a directed graph  and let $P_i$
be its vertices. Let $A$
be the corresponding adjacency matrix of $G$, i.e. $a_{i,j}=1$
if and only if there is a directed edge from $P_i$
to $P_j$, ($a_{i,j}=0$
otherwise).

Q. Any characterization  for directed graphs whose adjacency matrix admits only 0 as the eigenvalue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$0$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $A$ is nilpotent, which is equivalent to $A^n=0$. But $A^n=0$ expresses that for all $i$ and $j$, there is no path of length $n$ from $P_i$ to $P_j$. This in turn is equivalent to the graph containing no circles.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Many thanks for your attention.